# Django model @property failing silently

Tags: django, django-models

I'm just starting to mess with @property and I have one that seems to fail silently and I cannot figure out why:

```
class Tap(models.Model):

    beer = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ibu_actual =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
    og_actual = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,
            decimal_places=3, default=0)
    fg_actual = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,
            decimal_places=3, default=0)

    @property
    def calories(self):
        if (self.og_actual == 1 and self.fg_actual == 1):
            print "0 kCal"
            return 0
        else:
            calories_from_alcohol = (1881.22 * (self.fg_actual * (self.og_actual self.fg_actual)))
            calories_from_carbs = 3550 * self.fg_actual * ((0.1808 * self.og_actual) + (0.8192 * self.fg_actual) - 1.0004)
            print "%d kCal" % (calories_from_alcohol + calories_from_carbs)
            return calories_from_alcohol + calories_from_carbs
```

In my template, calories just returns a blank, and when running under 'runserver', my print string never shows up.  I added
    TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = "invalid string '%s'"
to my settings, and it shows that nothing is being generated for the template to show.
If I dumb down the calculations, for instance, set each to 1, then it works.
So I'm guessing that the math is making it fail for some reason?  A different property does work:

```
@property
def bugu(self):
#BU:GU is (ibu/((og-1)*1000)) if og > 1
    if self.og_actual > 1:
        print "bugu"
        return (self.ibu_actual/((self.og_actual-1)*1000))
    else:
        return 0
```

and my math works in the shell:

```
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> fg = 1.011
>>> og = 1.051
>>> fg + og
2.062
>>> (1881.22 * (fg * (og -fg)))
76.07653680000006
>>> 3550 * fg * ((0.1808 * og) + (0.8192 * fg) - 1.0004)
63.99993959999945
>>>
```

I'm not a python whiz by any means, so I'm stumped!

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I added a couple more debugging print statements, and the function is being entered:

```
Starting development server at http://192.168.0.15:7000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
bugu
starting calories
calculating calories from carbs
bugu
starting calories
calculating calories from carbs
bugu
starting calories
calculating calories from carbs
[13/Apr/2014 05:26:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7530
```

I tried swapping the order of the alcohol and carb calculations, but it doesn't seem to make a difference, it stops at either one.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that anything you print will show up in the template?

Comment: my print statement should show up under 'runserver' just before the http requests.  It does for the bugu property (and others) but does not for the calories function.  I'm not expecting something I print to be shown in my template.

Comment: Is that the only "calories" you have on the class or instances?

Comment: Yes it is the only calories.  If I replace my calculations with a value, the function executes and returns a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back into the Django shell and queried my object there and received an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Decimal'
```

and the answer to my problem here: https://github.com/plomino/Plomino/issues/308

So I converted my Decimal fields to floats and now it works.  I'll leave this for posterity and hopefully it will help someone else someday.